# Aggregate in Polars by appending lists

Tags: python, group-by, python-polars

In Python Polars, how can I aggregate by concatenating lists, rather than creating a nested list? For example, I'd like to aggregate this dataframe on id

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1],
    'name': [["Bob"], ["Mary", "Sue"]],
})
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["Bob"] |
| 1 | ["Mary", "Sue"] |

and get this result

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["Bob", "Mary", "Sue"] |

If I use `df.group_by('id').agg("name")`, I get a nested list, which I don't want:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [["Bob"], ["Mary", "Sue"]] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using explode on your name column.

```
result_df = df.group_by('id').agg(pl.col('name').explode())
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't exactly understand why this works-- `polars.Expr.explode` "means that every [list] item is expanded to a new row," https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.explode.html so I'm unclear on how this flattens (unpacks) a nested list.

Comment: @bwooster The [`.flatten()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.flatten.html) alias exists for that reason. The explode description makes more sense in the [DataFrame context.](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html#polars.DataFrame.explode)

Comment: I understand -- `.explode()` is making each item in a list in column `name` into its own row, which unpacks the list structure from `name`; then aggregating all those rows using the default method of creating a list. So it effectively flattens the list. Yes, in this context, I understand why the `.flatten()` alias exists and makes more sense -- `.flatten()` describes the effect on the output (aggregated) rather than the effect on the input (`name` column), even though the method is really acting on the input.